# PixiJS: not drawing round rectangle correctly

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

After drawing a rounded rectangle the corner is not perfectly rounded. The corner is pixelated:

[image]

How can I draw a correctly rounded rectangle without the pixelated corner? Here is my code:

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0x3e494b);
graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x0, .3);
graphics.drawRoundedRect(
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height,
    30
);
graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with PIXI in particular, but this looks like PIXI may be drawing to a `<canvas>` element whose internal size is smaller than its actual dimensions on the page. Make sure your canvas' internal dimension match or exceed the dimensions of the `<canvas>` HTML element.

Comment: @JohnEllmore Pixi.js defaults to WebGL and uses canvas as a fallback.

Comment: @Captain Is your Pixi application using WebGL or canvas?

Answer (score 3):

If your project uses a Pixi [Application](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html), try setting the antialias option to true. For example:

```
const app = new Application({antialias: true});
```